# Change tag "talking" into a synonym for "speech"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are 6 [questions tagged "talking"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) right now. The tag has no excerpt to explain its purpose.

In my opinion, the tag should become a synonym for [the "speech" tag](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) instead. **Should we do this?** What arguments can be put against this change?

While we're at it, some of the questions tagged "talking" could use more tags -- either "language" or "language-development" -- which I'd add at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

### This is complete

---

[talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) now contains 14 questions, and none of them greatly benefit from having that tag:

1. Talking doesn't have a wiki description yet, and probably doesn't need one
2. The talking questions all fall completely under one or more of the following tags:

   - [communication](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication)
   - [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech)
   - [language-development](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-development)
   - [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)

I propose editing the tags of the small number of existing questions to use the above tags instead, *and* making [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) a synonym for [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) for future questions.

Please note the limited use of the tag, and how it has not grown over the past 3 years. In fact, there have been no new [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) questions in over a year, whereas [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) has had 14 new questions since March alone, not to mention the other 3 similar tags.

---

I would undertake this myself, but I've already flooded the "active questions" list with a removal of a small number of "discussion" tags, and would like help spreading out these changes over time, and creating the synonym (you need at least 5 rep in the other tag, and I've answer/asked no "talking" questions, but I have rep in the other tags).

Comment: "I've already flooded the "active questions" list" - we've done this before; it's just a side effect of using the site. Don't worry about it! In fact, one could argue it's better to get all those mass-edits done in one go so that the "active questions" list will be disrupted for a shorter period of time. I'd say, go ahead. Perhaps a current mod could back me up?

Comment: @Torben On SF&F there's a soft policy of only doing a certain # per day, but if more is acceptable here then I'll do it.

Comment: We don't really have a policy at all, so if you have the time and inclination please feel free to edit tags :) if not, I should be able to some time in the next couple days.

Answer (score 1):

The tag wiki for [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) currently is:

> What is speech?
>
> Speech is the vocalized form of human communication. The subject of speech includes many subskills, such as vocabulary, grammar, pronunciation, enunciation.
>
> What questions should have this tag?
>
> - Questions about teaching your child to speak.
> - Questions about speech disabilities.
> - Questions about improving any area of speech skills.
> - General questions about speech disabilities.

Looking at the [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) questions, most of them seem to me to fall squarely under "questions about teaching your child to speak".  However, the focus of some are more precisely under the category of milestones.

We can address this by expanding the tag wiki for [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) to include "Questions about speech and communication milestones" to the "What questions should have this tag?" section.

There is one [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) question that seem more focused on the *behavior* of talking, rather than learning/disabilities/improving skills: [How to deal with incessant talking?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/how-to-deal-with-incessant-talking).  While it is a good question, I don't see the value of tagging it with either [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) or [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking).  The question is about the behavior, and the fact that the behavior involves speech is secondary to the question.

I'd suggest we simply remove [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) from that question.

Once we update the [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech) wiki, and remove [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) from that question, we should make [talking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking) a synonym for [speech](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech).

Comment: I agree with your "behavior" = "speech" judgment, but not sure about the first part: Aren't "questions about teaching your child to speak" exactly what the _language-development_ tag is for?

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun "Questions about teaching your child to speak" is what is *currently* in the [tag:speech] wiki.  How it relates to [tag:language-development] is a very good question... should it be incorporated into this question, or should we open a separate question for it?

Comment: Let's open a separate meta topic on that. It seems that we haven't been very careful with the speech/language-... tags and it wouldn't hurt to clean it up before we have hundreds of questions in these tags.